# Good Source of Differential Equations Problems with Worked Solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for a good source of problems for differential equations (first order, second order, laplace, convolution, systems).

I find it helpful if the question has a worked solution or at the very least a solution so that I can check my work and find my mistake, or try to get the solution given.

Thus far I haven't been able to find a great source, many websites have one or two questions with solutions but I need more so I can get a good amount of pratice.

Textbooks/Websites etc are all welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

- 2500 Solved Problems in Differential Equations, by Richard Bronson
- Schaum's Outline of Differential Equations, 4th by Richard Bronson, Gabriel Costa
- The Differential Equations Problem Solver, by David R. Arterburn, Staff of Research & Education Association

I think you can peruse both online and the price of each is cheap.

As far as sites go:

- [*Paul's Online Math Notes on DEQs*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/DE.aspx)
- [*MIT Open Courseware DEQs*](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/), also [*Video Lectures*](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/video-lectures/)
- [*Khan Academy - DEQs*](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations)
- [*Youtube - DEQs*](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwIFHT1FWIUJYuP5y6YEM4WWrY4kEmIuS)

Comment: Yeah most of those websites are great for explaining the topics, but not an abundant soucce of questions. I'll check the books out, thanks!