# Where should I begin learning about differential equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Right now I've worked my way to Taylor series derived from the Newton Gregory Interpolation formula, and don't have much understanding of linear algebra. Are there any good books/chapters/etc that introduce differential equations? They seem to be mostly related to physics.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755302/good-source-of-differential-equations-problems-with-worked-solutions

Comment: @Moo thanks alot!

Comment: You might gain some intuition from your starting point of Taylor and interpolation if you study the beginnings of numerical methods for ODE, the Euler methods of first and second order (explicit, implicit, modified, improved) and how their Taylor expansion relates to the Taylor expansion of an exact solution.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I ended up looking up Euler's method and appreciate the insight, I see the similarity right away with the Newton Gregory interpolation formula. I will say my main reason for learning these PDE's is the wave equation, namely to understand d'Alemberts. Sorry if this is too off topic, but will PDE's lead me to the fourier series?

Comment: Linear and quasi-linear PDE lead to Fourier transforms. The FT is used to define Sobolev spaces, these and related spaces play an important concept in the solution theory of PDE. The bridge from ODE to the spectral theory for PDE is usually made via Sturm-Liouville problems.